# Where should I inject bleach into a well with a pressure tank?

Tags: well-pump

Our pump works fine, but I do want to shock it after detecting some coliform. Thing is, I have no idea where to pour the bleach, there doesn't seem to be a simple well cap. I had my septic tank guy take a look as a favor, and he couldn't spot it either. Is it possible to DIY a well shock with a unit this old, or do I need to hire a professional to do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Picture of the other side of the pump? It's clearly a deep-well jet (two pipes down the well) so it must have a priming port on the pump - into which you can pour your bleach solution. But I can't see that port in the one picture provided. You should take a few minutes to clean up and/or dispose of some of the scary and code violating wire issues visible in this picture, as well.

Comment: By the way, when you *do* get to replacing it, consider a submersible pump. Jet pumps are a hold-over from an era when electric motors were much less reliable, and are significantly less efficient at turning electricity into water pumped. But as long as it works, might as well use it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! The wires are pretty creepy, as I'm mostly not sure what is vestigial and what is in service. I'll see about getting another picture up this afternoon.

Comment: Okay! Two more pics added. I'm not sure I see anything useful, but I'll leave it to you. Could that coupling at the top be it?

Comment: Not the angle I'd like for seeing the other side of the pump, but the top down view appears to show a square plug that might be in the right general area. On the other hand, why do I see two pressure switches and the cover of a third one lying on the ground? That is some weird wiring indeed. And the plumbing to the pressure switch that's on the motor is coming from whatever the heck that is poking out the top of the pump - looks like a half disassembled regulator. Which MAY be in the hole you need. Or it may have the hole you need in it, plugged...

Comment: Please clear up where the wires that go to and from the pressure switch near the blue tank go, and if the wires to the pressure switch on the pump visible in front of it are the same ones we can see disconnected. Can't trace the cables in that mess in these pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a [Myers HC/HCM](https://www.pentair.com/en-us/products/residential/water-supply-disposal/water-supply-pumps/myers-hc-hcm-series-convertible-deep-well-jet-pumps.html?queryID=fc9c3c099d451e9d77e3621b580282b0&objectID=https://www.pentair.com/en-us/products/residential/water-supply-disposal/water-supply-pumps/myers-hc-hcm-series-convertible-deep-well-jet-pumps.html&indexName=prod_pentair_products) deep well jet pump.

The [operating manual appears to be this one](https://www.pentair.com/content/dam/extranet/web/nam/myers/residential/manuals/13800a175-hcm-hc-ejecto-water-system-iom.pdf), but it shows that regulator on top as a functional thing with a pipe coming out of it, so your plumbing is truly weird at this point.

It mentions priming through a 1/2" plug on the regulator body - which might be the one on top of that.

It's also noted that the pipes to the well are attached by a flange, so the flange and be unbolted to access the pipes without having to unscrew the pipes. That would be another possible way to get chlorine solution into the well.

But the 2 pressure switches and parts of a third are confusing, and where, exactly, water is coming out of the pump into your pressure tank is not clear, since the pump manual shows it as coming out that regulator on top of the pump, and the pipe to the tank  just vanishes into the ground with no apparent connection to the pump. So I begin to wonder if this pump is even the pump (and well) you are actually using at this point? There's a mess of wires, some disconnected, making it unclear if it's even connected to power...

My best guess is that the well and pump we can see here may be decommissioned, and a deep well submersible pump is down some other well that the pipe and the wire from the pressure switch that's near the blue pressure tank are connected to.

Comment: The rusty old “Myers” pump is clearly not in service. The output is connected to nothing!